# Using two ids for a single Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a single plugin of jquery and I want to apply the same functionality to two different ids.

How can i achieve this, It is a type of next and previous functionality in which if we click on next then both the divs should scroll automatically..

If you see the html there are tow divs of same id which I should not use because the id should be unique if I am changing the id also how to call that id for the same plugin.

Request for the help

Here it is what I have tried.

```
stepcarousel.setup({
    galleryid: 'gallerya', //id of carousel DIV
    beltclass: 'belt', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
    panelclass: 'panel', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
    autostep: {enable:true, moveby:1, pause:3000},
    panelbehavior: {speed:300, wraparound:false, persist:false},
    defaultbuttons: {enable: true, moveby: 1, leftnav: ['images/left-arrow.png', 200, -30], rightnav: ['images/right-arrow.png', 10,  -30]},
    contenttype: ['inline'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['external', 'path_to_external_file']
})

div id="gallerya" class="stepcarousel" style="height:731px;">
                    <div class="belt">
                        <div class="panel" style="width:252px;">
                        <ul>
                        <li class="first leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/financial-analyst-interview-preparation.html" title=""> How to prepare for financial analyst interview?</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/external-training-programs-and-salary.html" title="">Are external training programs offered by company part of salary package?</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/preparation-for-an-interview/bank.html" title="">Bank Interview Preparation</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/prepare-for-campus-interview.html" title="">Best ways to Prepare for Campus Interview</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/preparation-for-an-interview/cognitive-abilities-tests" title="">Cognitive Abilities Test</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/preparation-for-an-interview/college.html" title="">College Interview Preparation</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/career-goals-in-job-interview.html" title="">Discussing career goals in a job interview</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/tools/dressing-tips" title="">Dressing up for Interview</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/top-100-questions/engg" title="">Engineering Interview Questions</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/favorite-job-destinations-in-india.html" title="">Favorite job destinations in India</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/top-100-questions/finance" title="">Finance Interview Questions</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/group-discussion-rules-for-interview.html" title="">Group Discussion Rules for Interview updated</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/dietician-interview-preparation.html" title="">How to Prepare for Dietician Job Interview</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/lab-technician.html" title="">How to Prepare for Lab Technician Interview?</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/pilot-interview-preparation.html" title="">How to Prepare for Pilot Interview</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/accounting.html" title="">How to Prepare for an Accounting Interview</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/insurance-agent-interview-preparation.html" title="">How to Prepare for an Insurance Agent Interview?</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/preparation-for-an-interview/how-to-answer-basic-interview-questions.html" title="">How to answer basic interview questions?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        </div> 

<div id="gallerya" class="stepcarousel" style="height:160px;">
                    <div class="belt">
                        <div class="panel">
                        <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/9779-project-manager.html"><b>Project Manager</u></b></a></span></span> <br />  
                            <span>A&amp;E Consulting</span><br />  
                            <span>Philippines </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <span><a href="http://www.jobzing.com/9779-project-manager.html"><b>Project Manager</u></b></a></span></span> <br />  
                            <span>A&amp;E Consulting</span><br />  
                            <span>Philippines </span>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                        </div>
```

[Page that I am creating](http://www.jobzing.com/Testt/inner-page.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

Call `.setup` once with `galleryid: 'galleryA'`, `beltclass: 'beltA'` and `panelclass: 'panelA'`.  And then again with `galleryid: 'galleryB'`, `beltclass: 'beltB'` and `panelclass: 'panelB'`.

```
stepcarousel.setup({
    galleryid: 'galleryA', //id of carousel DIV
    beltclass: 'beltA', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
    panelclass: 'panelA', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
    autostep: {enable:true, moveby:1, pause:3000},
    panelbehavior: {speed:300, wraparound:false, persist:false},
    defaultbuttons: {enable: true, moveby: 1, leftnav: ['images/left-arrow.png', 200, -30], rightnav: ['images/right-arrow.png', 10,  -30]},
    contenttype: ['inline'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['external', 'path_to_external_file']
})

stepcarousel.setup({
    galleryid: 'galleryB', //id of carousel DIV
    beltclass: 'beltB', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
    panelclass: 'panelB', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
    autostep: {enable:true, moveby:1, pause:3000},
    panelbehavior: {speed:300, wraparound:false, persist:false},
    defaultbuttons: {enable: true, moveby: 1, leftnav: ['images/left-arrow.png', 200, -30], rightnav: ['images/right-arrow.png', 10,  -30]},
    contenttype: ['inline'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['external', 'path_to_external_file']
})
```

And then your HTML like this:

```
<div id="galleryA" class="stepcarousel" style="height:731px;">
    <div class="beltA">
        <div class="panelA" style="width:252px;">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="galleryB" class="stepcarousel" style="height:160px;">
    <div class="beltB">
        <div class="panelB">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```